# Ionic Cordova Android: Input dispatching timed out ERROR

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crash, android-anr-dialog

We are running our android-app via cordova. Currently we are getting more and more ANR error-messages that the Input dispatching timed out.

Full error message:

**Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 17. Wait queue head age: 10815.7ms.)**

This is one of the logfiles where the error accoured:

```
  #00  pc 000000000008023c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 000000000014bf34  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #00  pc 0000000000383a84  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+436)
  #00  pc 000000000014de30  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NotifyHandler::handleMessage(android::Message const&)+108)
  #00  pc 0000000000017b80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+332)
  #00  pc 0000000000017994  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+56)
  #00  pc 0000000000166630  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:336)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:197)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Does anyone know why this error is caused in the main place? It seems kinda random to occur and at the moment we really don't know how to attac the error.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Still not able to fix this. Stil an open Issue

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm seeing the same issue all of a sudden on my Ionic project as well.

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using?